# missing values when saving model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When storing a new UserModel all that saves is

```
{ _id: 5d9e1ddf27c26e4aec7d3d20, __v: 0 }
```

Here is the Schema

```
const mongoose = require('../../db/index');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const OrganisationModel = require('../../models/organisations/index');

function hash(val) {
  'use strict';
  if (typeof val !== 'string') {
    val = '';
  }
  var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
  var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(val, salt);
  return hash;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  forename: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    set: hash
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  organisation: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: OrganisationModel,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

Here is the model

```
const mongoose = require('../../db/index');

const UserSchema = require('../../models/users/index');

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

And here is the saving

```
const UserModel = require('../models/users/index');

const user = new UserModel({
    forename: 'Tom',
    surname: 'Kiernan',
    password: 'test',
    email: 'test@example.com',
    organisation: '5d9e1a87cb220e7c64e7f8fb',
});

user.save(err => {
    if( err ) {
        console.log( err );
    }
    console.log( user );
});
```

Not specifically sure why it is only autogenerating the id and a version number what is happening to the rest of the info?

Also  as you may notice in the code above I am error logging the save function and it is not returning any errors.

Comment: Where is your `mongoose.model` method?

Comment: Will edit the post now sorry :(

Comment: Never seen `set: hash` before. Let me look at the docs, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Nope, I cannot find it, where did you get that `set` property of the schema property type?

Comment: So hash is a custom method I created that uses bcrypt and set is mongoose schema parameter, you can use set and get

Comment: Yeah, I see, but you cannot just reference the function into a Schema, either do it before storing a variable into a schema or use some of the build-in mongoose methods.

Comment: Look like you're requiring the schema here `const UserModel = require('../models/users/index');`?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Could you put this as the official answer? You where right I was requiring the UserModel and trying to use it as a schema. Needed changing to `const UserSchema = require('../../schema/users/index');`

Comment: What do you mean? I think UserModel in `const UserModel = require('../models/users/index');` is a schema but you used it as a model.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Almost but it's the opposite way round, I will post my solve to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

So I found my mistake because of a comment by @CuongLeNgoc

In model file I was requiring the model it's own file and trying to use it as the Schema.
Below is the updated file with notes

```
const mongoose = require('../../db/index');

// const UserSchema = require('../../models/users/index'); //Wrongly requiring the model again.
const UserSchema = require('../../schema/users/index'); // correctly requiring the schema 

const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```